High Error Values with Optuna in SARIMAX Parameter Optimization
I'm encountering issues with the SARIMAX algorithm while using it to forecast 1-step customer demand. The problem is that the error in the trials is very high, resulting in a large MAPE and RMSE (around 20%). Below is the dataframe I am working with:



ds
y




2021-01-11
135016.0


2021-02-24
255700.0


2021-04-09
123650.0


2021-05-23
466600.0


2021-07-06
467400.0


2021-08-19
685750.0


2021-10-02
279100.0


2021-11-15
252400.0


2021-12-29
330600.0


2022-02-11
228500.0


2022-03-27
585600.0


2022-05-10
521000.0


2022-06-23
879000.0


2022-08-06
515000.0


2022-09-19
728000.0


2022-11-02
336000.0


2022-12-16
286000.0


2023-01-29
531000.0


2023-03-14
384250.0


2023-04-27
727100.0


2023-06-10
477000.0


2023-07-24
864100.0


2023-09-06
433100.0


2023-10-20
611000.0


2023-12-03
296000.0


2024-01-16
299000.0


2024-02-29
570000.0


2024-04-13
47000.0



Here is the code I'm using:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_percentage_error
import optuna
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


def test_stationarity(timeseries):
    result = adfuller(timeseries)
    return result[1]  # ritorna il p-value

def make_stationary(timeseries):
    p_value = test_stationarity(timeseries)
    diff = 0
    while p_value > 0.05:
        timeseries = timeseries.diff().dropna()
        p_value = test_stationarity(timeseries)
        diff += 1
    return timeseries, diff


def optimize_sarimax(trial, train_data, test_data):
    p = trial.suggest_int('p', 0, 4)
    d = trial.suggest_int('d', 0, 2)
    q = trial.suggest_int('q', 0, 4)
    P = trial.suggest_int('P', 0, 4)
    D = trial.suggest_int('D', 0, 2)
    Q = trial.suggest_int('Q', 0, 4)
    s = trial.suggest_int('s', 6, 12)

    try:
        model = SARIMAX(train_data, order=(p, d, q), seasonal_order=(P, D, Q, s))
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)
        forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(test_data))
        error = mean_squared_error(test_data, forecast)
    except:
        error = np.inf
    
    return error

df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
df.set_index('ds', inplace=True)


stationary_series, diff_order = make_stationary(df['y'])


study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
study.optimize(lambda trial: optimize_sarimax(trial, stationary_series[:-2], stationary_series[-2:]), n_trials=250)

best_params = study.best_params

model = SARIMAX(df['y'], order=(best_params['p'], diff_order, best_params['q']),
                seasonal_order=(best_params['P'], best_params['D'], best_params['Q'], best_params['s']),freq=CFG.freq)
model_fit = model.fit(disp=False)


forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=1)
forecast_values = forecast


train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train, test = df['y'][:train_size], df['y'][train_size:]
model_fit = SARIMAX(train, order=(best_params['p'], diff_order, best_params['q']),
                    seasonal_order=(best_params['P'], best_params['D'], best_params['Q'], best_params['s'])).fit(disp=False)
forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(test))
rmse = mean_squared_error(test, forecast, squared=False)
mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(test, forecast)

print(f'RMSE: {rmse}')
print(f'MAPE: {mape}')


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(df.index, df['y'], label='Serie Storica', color='blue')
forecast_dates = pd.date_range(start=df.index[-1], periods=3, freq='MS')[1:]
plt.plot(forecast_dates, forecast_values, marker='o', color='red', label='Previsione')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


Issues I'm Facing:
High Error Rates: The error rates (RMSE and MAPE) are very high, suggesting the model is not fitting well.
What I've Tried:

I run the code with another data frame and it works good
I tried different aggregation (this one is 44D, I also tried W, M, 10D) but nothing changed
I manually differentiated the series two times (in order to have a p-value < 0,05) but nothing changed
Different parameters ranges but nothing changed

Questions:
Are there any improvements I can make to the model or the approach to achieve better convergence and lower error rates?
Is there any particular aspect of the data or the SARIMAX model that I might be overlooking?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
